# Convert excel file to PDF using Java API

Tags: excel, pdf

I have an Excel file that has multiple graphic content  (a normal excel file).

[image]

I am reading this file using POI API in java. I am able to convert the file to PDF table using iText jar.

But, the whole format is not copied into the PDF. (e.g., merged cells come into one column, and other formatting or settings are all gone).

A simple pdf table is created like below.
[image]

However when I convert with MS Excel and save as PDF i get the below output which has all the formatting details and looks perfect.

[image]

How do i retain the same format as in excel? I have done some googling on this and got some methods like OpenOffice API but all of them convert files on local machine. What if I send my tomcat build to client machine where OpenOffice is not installed ? Need some solution for that. Any help would be useful.

Comment: Does OpenOffice actually convert the way you expect, the same as MS Excel? Why not tell your client to install MS Office or OpenOffice? It is not quite clear what the exact issue is for you, since MS Excel generates what you want. Perhaps you could elaborate on what your requirements are.

Comment: My exact issue is I want to convert excel to PDF through my java code exactly how MS Excel does , with formatting and everything and I am not able to achieve that with POI and IText. Also I would prefer creating a PDF from scratch rather than suggesting client to install OpenOffice so that is also out of question.

Comment: "I want to convert excel to PDF through my java code exactly how MS Excel does". The only way to get the exact output as Excel is to use Excel. Note, that even different versions of Excel will display the same Excel file differently. This is the same for all Office formats. This is one of the main reasons PDF format is so popular, is that it is the best format for ensuring rendering accuracy on any device, while also supporting vector and text. If your clients want perfect reproduction, they should generate their own PDF files.

Comment: "The only way to get the exact output as Excel is to use Excel" - Agreed, Although if I use any online conversion website like online2pdf.com, I still get perfect results. Hence thinking there might be some other way with which I can achieve that.